# what privilege is needed for a user to create table in another schema

Tags: sql, postgresql, create-table, sql-grant

I have a user `rafal` and I want to create a table in another schema.
I do it like this:

```
grant usage on schema tony to rafal,
```

but when I try to create a table, I still get errors:

```
create table tony.t1(a int);

ERROR:  permission denied for schema tony
```

and I also grant like this:

```
grant all on schema tony to rafal;
```

Is there any other privileges needed? I tried to search but can not find useful information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The user would need the `CREATE` privilege.

```
grant usage, create on schema tony to rafal;
```